# Accidentally removed vendor folder in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, composer-php

I was working with a laravel project and, accidentally, removed `vendor` folder.

What should I do? Create a new project and copy it or download it anywhere else?

I had no additional composer dependencies installed.

Comment: Do you have versioning? git or svn

Comment: composer install, if you run composer update itll take your packages to the newest version.

Comment: Yes. I was versioning with Git. That was the cause, I accidentaly added the vendor into the repository, so, trying to remove it, removed the folder itself.Anyways, composer install worked for me. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @Luiz Accept the Answer submitted.

Comment: Thank you Sari Yono, this lessens the dependency problems

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just run `composer install` after `cd`ing into the Laravel project's directory.

Answer (score 2):

The Vendor folder is created by running `composer install`. It contains only the packages which you have asked composer to track in the `composer.json` file. If you have a `composer.phar` file in the root of your application run `php composer.phar install`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md is probably your best source for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Laravel 10** and sail commands, **sail** will stop working after removing the **vendors** folder.

You can fix by making sure your project is up:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and entering the container with:

```
docker exec -it  <<projectname>>-laravel.test-1 bash
```

Then running composer again:

```
composer install
```